# Traefik not detecting containers running in network_mode=host (192.168.99.x)

Tags: docker, traefik

i am running traefik container in **dockertoolbox** with default network bridge
and one more container running on network_mode=host
but the traefik is detecting the service with 127.0.0.1 instead of DockerHost
IP= 192.168.99.x
can anyone help me with this

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  reverse_proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "81:80"
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - backend


 whoami:
   image: containous/whoami
   labels:
     - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:whoami.localhost"
     - "traefik.enable=true"
     - "traefik.backend=whoami"
     - "traefik.port=80"
   network_mode: host
   restart:
     always

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

**NOTE**: using **dockertoolbox** in **windows** **10**

Comment: anybody knows ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you’re having?  Is there a specific reason you _need_ host networking, or can you switch the other container to be on the same Docker network as the proxy?

Comment: when the service container is ran in the same network as traefik proxy, then in Traefik WEBUI the container IP is shown . because of this when i click on this container ip , it says timed out

Comment: i have included the docker-compose file... please refresh

Comment: anbody ... please look into this